# ROC (Epi library) how to calculate TP, FN,TN, FP

Tags: r, roc

I'm trying to find how to compute the true negative (TN), false negative (FN), true positive (TP), and false positive (FP) if I have a cutpoint like in the following picture:

[image]

```
library(Epi)
dane = read.table("dane.txt", header=TRUE, sep=";")       
ROC(form = stan~palenie, plot="ROC", data=dane)
```

Comment: Please give the motivation for not using traditional risk estimation.  The procedure you are describing has a very strange utility (cost/loss) function in terms of decision analysis.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure about the Epi package, never used it before.  However, this is easily done in the pROC package (?coords) and in the ROCR package (?performance).  Best of luck.

Answer (score 1):

You can use following formulas:

amount of True Positives (TP) = (True Positive Rate(sensitivity))*(amount of positive examples);

amount of True Negatives (TN) = (True Negative Rate(specificity))*(amount of negative examples);

amount of False Positives (FP) = (1 - True Negative Rate)*(amount of negative examples)

amount of False Negatives (FN) = (1 - True Positive Rate)*(amount of positive examples)